# Auto Import With Eclipse Snippets

Tags: eclipse

I started using snippets recently. The most common one I use inserts this at the cursor:

```
private Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());
```

However, I still have to do a CTRL-SHIFT-O to import Logger and LoggerFactory.

Out of pure laziness I ask this: Is there a way to do an automatic import when I insert this snippet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think a Snippet can automatically insert an import statement (or do *anything* other than insert text at the current cursor location). But you can set up an automatic **Save Action** to do the organize imports whenever you save. Open the project properties and navigate to **Java Editor** > **Save Actions**.

I usually set up a few different things in the **Additional Actions** including Organize Imports, removed trailing whitespace, insert missing annotations, etc.